# How to upgrade existing phpmyadmin version in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, installation, upgrade

My current version of PHPMYADMIN is phpMyAdmin 3.3.2 .

I want to upgrade to the latest phpmyadmin version.

I used following command

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I also tried

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

When i am using the above command, it is asking to

Since you are reconfiguring phpmyadmin, you may also want to reinstall
   the database which it uses.

If you wish to reinstall the database for phpmyadmin, you should select
  this option.  If you do not wish to do so (if you are reconfiguring the
  package for unrelated reasons), you should not select this option.

Reinstall database for phpmyadmin?

I am selecting no. I do not want to delete all the database.

I just want to upgrade it to latest.
http://www.oldapps.com/phpmyadmin.php?old_phpmyadmin=12551

Please help.

Comment: I think this question belongs on another stack exchange site since it's not programming related.  Try http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps this may be of some use to you: http://duckranger.com/2012/03/upgrade-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest available version of phpmyadmin from the official ubuntu [package repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=phpmyadmin&searchon=names&suite=lucid&section=all) for 10.04 is 3.3.2, that means you can't update to the latest version using that sources.

To install the newest version, you can either

- download and install the new version from the homepage manually
- install from a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html) - there are [several](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=phpmyadmin) available.

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response. I tried from the package repository. I added deb url in /etc/apt/source.list file. But it is not allowed to get the ppa package from the respected package. And it is also not able to allow me to apt-get update command. Please let me know.

Comment: this [link](https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html) explains how to add a ppa's key to the keyring and use it.